# Virtual directory, Uncaught SyntaxError

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, virtual-directory

I have a virtual directory with the same website that I have on the main path.

But, when I'm trying to load the same page inside the virtual directory, the page is not rendered fine, and I'm getting an error on the browser:

- http://MyStie/Cars/Index
- http://MyStie/VirtualDirectory/Cars/Index

Error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

In order to redirect the path to the aspx view, I'm using the following code:

```
  routes.MapPageRoute("MapPageCarsIndex", "Cars/Index","~/Views/Cars/index.aspx");
```

Using the same project on the main Path works like a charm, but on the virtual directory not.. what I'm missing to do?

I have a different Pool for the virtual directory, and also in visual studio I have the same error when I'm using the virutual directory from IIS Express.

Comment: That is a javascript error

Comment: Yeah, I thought that was a javascript error, but on the main path, the site is working fine without js errors... ><'

Comment: Yes you are right! was a javascript error! lOOOl, ty very much the javascript was calling the main site path to retrieve data, crazy!!!